# Save value from custom Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have created a new preference which directly extends from `CheckboxPreference`. In this class I added a simple new `boolean` value. My question now is how I have to store this new value. If a user clicks a normal `CheckboxPreference` the value is stored automaticly in the preferences. I want that this happens also with my new value. For this I think I have to overwrite a method but I do not know which of them. Also I have two `boolean` values now (checked and my own) so I have to build a logic or something like this with integers because there are four different possibilities with two booleans. So how can I store my two values efficiently and which method do I have to overwrite for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SharedPreference` ,which you store value and key pairs. For example key is "colorPreference" and value is "green". It doesn't get deleted even if you close app.

//Setting shared preference

```
public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesFDefault;
sharedPreferencesFDefault = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

//Adding something you want

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit();
editor.putInt("studentNameColor", 2); // studentNameColor=2 for example
editor.commit();
```

//Getting value you have stored

```
int color = sharedPreferencesFDefault.getInt("studentNameColor", -1); // gets 2, if this key is not found, returns -1
```

//Deleting `key-value` pair if no need anymore

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit();
editor.remove("studentNameColor");
editor.commit();
```

//Delete every `key-value` pair inside defaultSharedPreference

```
sharedPreferencesFDefault.edit().clear().commit();
```

Also you can use `apply()` instead of `commit()` which does operations asynchronously in background.