# How to save permanently information in a variabile

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm new in Android development , and I have to create an app which allow user to scan a wifi network , select an access point and get information like ip address and mac address . When I've got these information , I want to be Able to save it in a "Favorites Activity" .
I asked that question , because I have to send to 4-5 computers a string , but I do not want to search for this devices each time I open the app.

At the end, I want to conserve this informations in a variable,  and when I click on a determinated button, open another activity that makes me view these informations.

The network informations i think i'll be able to extract it (List `ScanResult`, `getIpAddr`), and also save it in a variable, but scares me that this information must be saved permanently.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Take a look [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to save permanent.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences . Here is a demo - http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *two* options:

**1)** `SharedPreference`, which you store `key`-`value` pairs. Say key `name1` refers to `myWindowsDevice`. And then whenever you want to use it, you can get name of PC from `name1` key. Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29513231/3736955).

**2)** `Database`, you store your data in `database` table and get it whenever you want. Usage is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

In your case, i think `database` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

With SharedPreferences you can save the information and have it in all activities.

Check the SharedPreferences info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html