# How to save/load BigInteger array

Tags: java, android, casting, sharedpreferences, biginteger

I want to save/load a `BigInteger` array into/from the SharedPreferences.
How can it be done?

For example for the following array:

```
private BigInteger[] dataCreatedTimes = new BigInteger[20];
```

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513056/save-value-from-custom-preference/29513231#29513231

Answer (score 1):

Consider `bigInts` is the `BigInteger[]` you want from `Preference`:

```
BigInteger[] bigInts = new BigInteger[n];
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

for(BigInteger bigInt : bigInts) {
    set.add(bigInt.toString());
}

//store into Preference
SharedPreference.Editor editor = getSharedPreference(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putStringSet("bigints", set);

//get BitInteger[] from Preference
SharedPreference pref = getSharedPreference(getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Set<String> set = pref.getStringSet("bigints", new HashSet<String>());
int count = set.size();

String[] strs = new String[count];
BigInteger[] bigInts= new BigInteger[count];
set.toArray(strs);

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    bitInts[i] = new BigInteger(strs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SilentKnight : But i get below error "The method add(String) in the type Set<String> is not applicable for the arguments (BigInteger)" in line "set.add(bigInt)"

Comment: Also getting below error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method toArray(Object[]) from the type Set" in line "Set.toArray(strs);"

Comment: Try again. PS: are you a beginner?

Comment: I m sorry, i didn't see the "S" in Set. My bad. Yes beginner in Android. My Apology. I will check and let you know if it is working. Thanks once again

Comment: in my eyes the best solution to get the most out of the API. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you can convert to a json `String` and back, which then of course makes it trivial to save in preferences:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public final class BigIntegerArrayJson {    
    private BigIntegerArrayJson(){}

    public static String toJson(BigInteger[] array) {
        return new Gson().toJson(array);
    }

    public static BigInteger[] fromJson(String json) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, BigInteger[].class);
    }
}
```

To add Gson in gradle add dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String DELIMITER = "BOND";
    final int DELIMITER_LENGTH = 4;
    String str = "";
    BigInteger[] integer = new BigInteger[50];

    for(int i = 0; i < integer.length ; i++) {
        str += integer[i].toString() + DELIMITER;
    }

 savePreference("your_key", str);
```

and here's your save preference method

```
public static void savePreference(String iName, String iValue) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                MainApplication.getsApplicationContext()).edit();
        // Check that passed key is not null
        if (iName != null && iValue != null) {
            editor.putString(iName, iValue);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

Now to get back your BigInteger Values ,

```
String str = loadPreference("your_key");
ArrayList<BigInteger> myBigInt = new ArrayList<>();


        while(str != null){
            int subStringLastIndex = 0;
            if(str.contains(DELIMITER) && str.length() != DELIMITER_LENGTH){
              subStringLastIndex = str.indexOf(DELIMITER.charAt(0));
            myBigInt.add(new BigInteger(str.substring(0, subStringLastIndex)));
            str = str.substring(subStringLastIndex + 4);

            }else{
                str = null;
            }
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < myBigInt.size(); i++){
        Log.d(TAG, myBigInt.get(i).toString());
    }
```

Here's your loadPreference Method

```
public static String loadPreference(String iName) {
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainApplication.getsApplicationContext()).
                    getString(iName,null);
        }
```

Note : You can change delimiter what ever you want, but prefer to take character array. Change Delimiter length accordingly

Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: Dabrai - Thanks, Can you also post Retrieval Method ? Will i get my data back in arrays while retrieving ? I will check and let you know

Comment: you might want to use StringBuilder when concatenating in a loop.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, this is working, only problem i am facing is while retrieving i am getting results printed for 20 times, which means i will receive same entry for 20 times. What could be issue here?

Comment: nothings seems wrong at my end, are you sure that array has distinct elements? because that's the only reason looks here.